# find probability distirbution of defective item

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

when 2 defective items are extracted one by one in a partition consisting of 6 products and checked, Let x be the number of test before finding the last defective items
fing probability distribution of X

i realize the possibility are: 
D=defective, N=Non defective 
X=0 , DD 
X=1, NDD 
X=2, NNDD 
X=3, NNNDD
X=4 , NNNNDD

$\mathbb P(X=2)=\frac{{{2\choose 2}}}{{6\choose 2}}$

$\mathbb P(X=3)=\frac{{{2\choose 2}}{{4\choose 1}}}{{6\choose 2}}$

$\mathbb P(X=4)=\frac{{{2\choose 2}}{{4\choose 2}}}{{6\choose 2}}$

$\mathbb P(X=5)=\frac{{{2\choose 2}}{{4\choose 4}}}{{6\choose 2}}$

is this right?

Comment: Do your probabilites sum to 1?

Comment: no, in the back of the book, $P(X=3)=\frac{2}{15}$, i dont know how to get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X=k)$ is the probability that at the $kth$ try you found the second defective, and in the first $k-1$ tries you found only one defective. So $$\begin{align}P(X=k)=\frac{\text{number of ways of choosing 1 defective from k-1 tries}}{\text{number of ways of choosing k-1 objects from six}}&=\frac{k-1\choose1}{6\choose k-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: thankyou so much!! so the last one must be defective? another way is like when order matter but permute the first k-1 part P(X=3) = $\frac{4}{6} \frac{2}{5} \frac{1}{4} 2 = \frac{2}{15}$  also ok? its a bit hard at first to come up , with function for probability distribution

Comment: The last try must be defective because you stop when you have found the second defective. No reason to continue trying (you have already found both of the defectives). Using permutations let $D_i$ be the event that the $ith$ object chosen is defective and $D_i^c$ the event that the $ith$ object chosen is not defective. Therefore $P(X=3)=P(D_1\cap D_2^c\cap D_3)+P(D_1^c \cap D_2 \cap D_3)=(4/6)(2/5)(1/4)+(4/6)(2/5)(1/4)$ which is your answer.

Comment: thankyou so much!! :D

Comment: Hello im sorry to ask again! is this equation also possible $\frac{4C{x-1} *2C1}{6Cx-1}$ i dont get the right answer but i mean you know the point(?)

Comment: The formula is not correct for what you mean to do. Putting $x=3$ The numerator means: number of ways to choose 2 non defectives from the four non defectives, and 1 defective from the two defectives. It means you have two non defectives and 1 defective. This is not the event $X=3$ because you have not found the second defective. What you mean I guess is $\frac{{4\choose x-2} {2\choose 1}}{6\choose x-1}$ But this is also not correct because we do not force the 3rd try to be the second defective. Since there is 1 defective out of four. We must divide by 4.

Comment: Thus $P(X=3)=\frac{{4\choose 1} {2\choose 1}}{6\choose 2}\frac{1}{4}$. And $P(X=n)=\frac{{4\choose x-2} {2\choose 1}}{6\choose x-1}\frac{1}{6-(n-1)} $